# How to make python auto-select right pyc file to execute?

Tags: python, pyc

I want to distribute my python script in `pyc` format(generated by `python -OO -m py_compile run.py`)

For different python versions, I've created `run.cpython-36.pyc`, `run.cpython-38.pyc`...

Now, if the users are using python3.6, they need to call `python run.cpython-36.pyc`, if they are using python3.8. they need to call `python run.cpython-38.pyc`. This is not convenient, how can I make python to auto-select the right `pyc` file to execute such that the user don't need to bother choosing the right version?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one solution: use a proxy script.

Something like:

```
# run_proxy.py

try:
  import run_36 as m
except ImportError:
  import run_38 as m

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # delegation
  m.Run()
```

And the users just call `python run_proxy.py`